# How to send message to specific user using socket_io_client flutter package

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io, chat

I am trying to build an chat apps using socket.io and node.js for backend and flutter for frontend... so far I have been trying to send message to all connected user, is there a way to send message to specific user? here is part of my backend code

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`id: ${socket.id}`)
  socket.on('send_message', (msg) => {
    var detail = JSON.parse(msg)
    socket.in(detail["receiver"]).emit('to_user', msg)
  })
});
```

in flutter I am using socket_io_client package (https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/socket_io_client) but I don't know how to emit message for specific user
here is part of code for frontend

```
StreamController<String> _data = StreamController<String>();

  socket.on('send_message', (x) {
      _data.sink.add(x);
  });

  sendChat(String msg, String sender, String receiver) {
    Map map = {"msg": msg, "snd": sender, "rcv": receiver};
    var mapbody = json.encode(map);
    socket.emit('send_message', mapbody);
  }

Stream<String> get sendChat => _data.stream;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to  have the socket.id and use io.sockets.socket(SocketId).emit(msg) to send message

```
var express = require("express");
var redis = require("redis");
var sio = require("socket.io");
var client = redis.createClient()
var app = express.createServer();
var io = sio.listen(app);
io.set("store", new sio.RedisStore); 
// In this example we have one master client socket 
// that receives messages from others.
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
// Promote this socket as master
socket.on("I'm the master", function() {
// Save the socket id to Redis so that all processes can access it.
client.set("mastersocket", socket.id, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Master socket is now" + socket.id);
});
});
socket.on("message to master", function(msg) {
   // Fetch the socket id from Redis
client.get("mastersocket", function(err, socketId) {
  if (err) throw err;
  io.sockets.socket(socketId).emit(msg);
});
});
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help... Do you know how to imolement ```io.sockets.socket(socketId).emit(msg)``` from client side of flutter?

Answer (score 0):

some options you have here.

first :

you can store your connected clients ids to redis .

use [io-redis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) :

and store your client id in it:
for storing ids in redis:

```
await redisClient.lpush(`socket_members`, socket.id);
```

for getting the specefic id:

```
let client = await redisClient.lrange(
               `socket_members`,
               0,
               socket.id
            );
```

the second option is you can create an authentication middleware

```
const jwt = async(socket, next) => {
    let token = socket.handshake.query.token
    let verify = jwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, jwt_encryption, async(err, decoded) => {
       // find user with decoded token 
       
        if (!user) {
            return next(new Error(JSON.stringify({ status: 401, message: 'unuthorized' })));

        }
        socket.user = user._doc
        return next()

    })

};
```

and use it in socket io instance :

```
io.use(jwt);
```

the authenticated user is in **socket.user**.

hope this would help

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, do you have any example how to implement the first option in client side of flutter?

Comment: @uyhaW look at the example